# What email verified my website with Google Webmaster Tools?

Tags: google-search-console

My website has the meta tag that Google Webmaster Tools uses to verify website ownership:

```
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="[base 64 string]" />
```

Is there a way to figure out what google account / email verified the website?

Without knowing the email associated with the existing code is it possible to sign in to the website's Google Webmaster Tools account without changing the code in the meta tag?

Comment: have you tried base64-decoding that string?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about finding a forgotten email address.

Comment: @MarcB I tried that. The string is not the right length to be an actual Base-64 char array or string

Comment: It's a random string tied to an account and site. Trying to decode it is futile.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have the site verified yourself, you can see the verified owners at 
`https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/user-admin?hl=en&siteUrl={YOUR_VERIFIED_SITE}`. Otherwise there's no way to learn whose verification string is that.

Comment: Going to that URL, I have to sign in to my Google account, then it says: "You are signed in as username@gmail.com, and you can't view details for www.example.com. Verify to get access.". I'm going to take the route of reverification (replacing the existing `<meta>` tag).